# Does anyone know how to refesh my Q?

Tags: user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

I have created a maths game and when I load the first questions its fine, if i get the answer right the score increases by 100  but then when it loads the next question, it loads it directly on top of the old one and the score no longer increases.

Also my counter doesn't work to end the game.

Can anyone help please ?

```
 def do_question(self):
            ##    def create_widgets(self):
                    #counter here if over 5 then die
                    counter = 0
                    counter += 1
                    #counter + 1
                    if counter > 5:
                        import ITRIED

                SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tblQuestion'
                cursor = Databaseconnector.SELECT(SQL)
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
                random_row = random.choice(rows)

                print random_row.QuestionID, random_row.Question, random_row.Hint, random_row.A1, random_row.A2, random_row.A3, random_row.A4, random_row.CorrectAnswer

                self.a1button = Tkinter.Button(self, background="blue",foreground="white", text = (random_row.A1), command = self.QUESTION1)
                self.a1button.grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = 'W')
```

Question checker:

```
             def QUESTION1(self):
                score = int(self.label7['text'])
                if self.a1button['text'] == self.label6['text']:
                    tkMessageBox.showinfo("CORRECT", "WELL DONE")
                    score = +100
                    self.do_question()
                else:
                    tkMessageBox.showinfo("INCORRECT", "YOU GOT IT WRONG :/")
                    label7 = +100
                    self.do_question()
                self.label7.config(text=str(score))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counter will never be over five because you reset it to zero every time do_question is called. Plus, the way you have it coded, counter is a local variable. The first thing you need to do is make counter an instance variable (ie: self.counter) so that it's no longer local to a single function.

The same holds true for the score variable -- it is local to a function instead of being an instance variable.

As for why it "loads it directly on top of the old one", it's because you're telling it to do that. In do_question, you're using grid to place the button at row 9, column 1. You aren't ever removing what might have already been at row 9, column 1. You should call `grid_remove` or `grid_forget` on the previous question before making the new question visible.